# Disabling asp button when no items selected in list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I would like my button to be disabled if no items are are selected in the Listbox. I have the button Enable set to false. When an item is selected the button does enable true, however, after the button is enabled it will not disable when there no list items selected.

Code behind:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> itemsRemove = new List<ListItem>();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
            itemsRemove.Add(listItem);

    }

    foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsRemove)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(listItem);
    }


}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            Button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Enabled = false;

    foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            Button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not the best solution for such functionality, it is better to use some javascript code to enable/disable your button.

EDIT (minimal solution):

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Enabled = ListBox1.Items.Any(x => x.Selected);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and advice. Unfortunately this did not correct the issue. The button is still enabled after removing the selected items.

Comment: Move `Button2.Enabled = false;` to Page_Load or call `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method in button click handler

Answer (score 0):

You should also set `AutoPostBack` property of `ListBox` to `true` and also `EnableViewState` of both button and `ListBox` must be set to `true`.

Comment: Please move your answer to a comment, or edit the existent answer